# In C# I have implemented a custom exception, how do I now implement it?

Tags: c#, try-catch, tic-tac-toe, custom-exceptions

I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe game for an assignment and I am new to C#. I have a custom exception for bad moves called `BadMoveException`, which would be if the user enters anything other than 0-8. There is existing code for the assignment and I'm wondering if I should do away with the code to create my own to use this exception or if it is easy enough to implement here? Here is the code:

```
string input;
int position;
do
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
} 
while (!int.TryParse(input, out position));
```

I need to catch the `BadMoveException`, and any others with an unknown error message. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `BadMoveException` inherits from `Exception`, then you can use it just like any other `Exception`, like this:

```
try {
    //do stuff
    if (badMove) {
        throw new BadMoveException();
    }
} catch (BadMoveException) {
    //user made a bad move!!
} catch {
    //something else went wrong
}
```

There is more information about exception handling here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have:

1- First, your exception need to inherit from Exception like this:

`public class BadMoveException : Exception { // Your code here }`

2- When you have an error, you use it like this:

`throw new BadMoveException(// Enter parameter if you have any in you class);`

And you catch it:

```
try
{
    if(Position < 0 || Position > 8) 
    { 
         throw new BadMoveException(// Enter parameter here if you have any);
    }
    else
    {
         // Your code here
    }
}
catch(BadMoveException bmex) { // Show message here }
catch(Exception ex) { // Show other exception }
```

Hope it helps !

Links for documentation: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/custom-exception-csharp
https://stackify.com/csharp-exception-handling-best-practices/